# Question regarding kinetic energy of a body

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work

Suppose you pushed a block very hard for a small interval of time. Then it traveled some distance 'S' and stops due to friction.

You haven't applied force upto the 'S' distance. The force applied by you had existed only for small interval of time.

My question is: do the work done by you can be  given by
W=F.S ?

If not , then how will you find the work done?

Answer (score 2):

You stop doing work on the block as soon as you stop applying a force on it. The rest of the work is done by friction.

Comment: What if , there is no friction at all. Then the block will continue to move with constant velocity. What will be the work done?

Comment: The work done by you (the external force) will be the force applied multiplied by the distance you applied it for. After you stop applying the force, the work being done on the block will be zero, if you ignore friction.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is: do the work done by you can be given by W=F.S ?

No, because the work done by the applied force is only over the distance covered during the application of the force. You have described the distance $S$ as that covered *after the force* is applied.

Let's assume the distance covered during the application of the force is $d$ and that the average force over the distance is $F$. Then the work done by person pushing the block is $Fd$.

But in order to determine the change in kinetic energy we need to account for the negative work done by friction over the distance $d$. That's because the change in kinetic energy of the block equals the *net work done* on the block, not just the work done by the person pushing the block.

The kinetic friction force opposing the applied force is

$$f_{k}=-\mu_{k}mg$$

where $\mu_{k}$ is the coefficient of kinetic friction, $m$ is the mass of the block, and $g$ the acceleration due to gravity.

Then the net force on the block is

$$F_{net}=F-\mu_{k}mg$$

And the net work done is

$$W_{net}=(F-\mu_{k}mg)d$$

Assuming the block started at rest, then kinetic energy of the block at the distance $d$ equals the net work done, or

$$\frac{1}{2}mv^{2}=(F-\mu_{k}mg)d$$

Where $v$ is the velocity of the block at the time the force is removed.

One final point. Once the applied force is removed, then the only force doing work on the block is the kinetic friction force doing negative work on the block. From that, you can determine the stopping distance S since the net work done is negative work done by kinetic friction and that will equal the loss of kinetic energy, or

$$-\mu_{k}mgS=-\frac{1}{2}mv^2$$

$$S=\frac{v^2}{\mu_{k}g}$$

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The work done is $F$ times the distance that it moved during the short time you were pushing.  The distance it moved later is not relevent.

Answer (score 1):

If you pushed the block with a force $\vec F$ a small distance $\delta x$ parallel to $\vec F$, then the work done on the block is simply $\boxed{F. \delta x }$. If you would like to express it in terms of the distance travelled afterward($S$) and the kinetic friction ($f_k$), you can use the following approach:

For the short interval where work was done: $$\Delta K +f_k.\delta x= W_{ext} \rightarrow W_{ext} = K_i + f_k.\delta x$$
and for the rest of the block's motion: $$\Delta K + f_k.S = 0 \rightarrow K_i = f_k.S$$
Consequently, $$\boxed{W_{ext} = f_k.(S +\delta x) \approx f_k.S}$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't understand the mathematical part of your answer. Pls explain

Comment: Which part did you not understand? I just used the work-kinetic energy theorem. The "work done" by friction in each case is just -Force x Distance = -$f_k .d$

Comment: Work done is equal to change in kinetic energy . Work done is equal to force times displacement. Why you mix both the equation?

Comment: I have another silly question. Why the work done is equal to change in kinetic energy? Why it is not equal to Change in potential energy ?

Comment: (1) $W = \Delta K$ (2) $W = F.d$. In the presence of friction, work is done by the force and the frictional force too, so $W_{force} - f_k.d = \Delta K$ which is my first equation (with d replaced by $\delta x$)

Comment: That is a seperate question in itself. Simply put, a single particle cannot posess a potential energy.

Comment: Why the 'Ki' is not negative

Comment: $∆K = K_i - 0$ in the first equation. I assumed it started from rest, and kinetic energy is never negative

Comment: The mathematics behind this answer is only if there is friction, and finding a mathematical relation between the work done, and the stopping distance.   A better way of you understanding is as follows. From a to b, you apply a force F to the body  and then from b onwards there is no applied force, apart from friction, at which point the  block stops.  $$\int_{a}^{b} (\vec{F} + \vec{F}_{f}) \cdot \vec{dr} + \int_{b}^{c} \vec{F}_{f}  \cdot \vec{dr}= 0$$ as it moves from a to b, there is 2 forces friction and applied, then once it moves from b to some distance B the only.force is friction, such

Comment: That, at point c, the net work is zero, aka "stopping", depending on what relation you want you can solve for what ever you like to get that in terms of stopping distance.  Please note that F.dr isn't the work done when pushing, as there is also a frictional force when you push aswell

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: do the work done by you can be given by W=F.S ?

No, because the work done by the applied force is only over the distance covered during the application of the force. You have described the distance $S$ as that covered *after the force* is applied.

> If not , then how will you find the work done?

To find the work done by the person pushing the block, you need to determine the distance $d$ that the person accelerates the block. Then the work done by the person will be $W=Fd$ where $F$ is the constant force applied by the person over the distance $d$.

In order to calculate the distance $d$ we start with Newton’s second law relating the acceleration $a$ of the block to the *net applied force* $F_{net}$

$$a=\frac{F_{net}}{m}\tag{1}$$

Now it is important to recognize there are two forces acting on the block, the applied force $F$ and the kinetic friction force $f_k$ which opposes the applied force and is given by

$$f_{k}=-\mu_{k}mg\tag{2}$$

where $\mu_{k}$ is the coefficient of kinetic friction, $m$ is the mass of the block, and $g$ the acceleration due to gravity. The kinetic friction force is generally considered to be constant for low speeds.

So the net force is

$$F_{net}=F-\mu_{k}mg\tag{3}$$

Substituting $F_{net}$ from equation (3) into equation (1)

$$a=\frac{(F-\mu_{k}mg)}{m}\tag{4}$$

From kinematics, the distance $d$ covered for constant acceleration $a$ over time $t$ is

$$d=\frac{1}{2}at^2\tag{5}$$

Substituting $a$ from equation (4) into equation (5)

$$d=\frac{(F-\mu_{k}mg)}{2m}t^2$$

The work $W$ done by the person accelerating the block ($F\gt f_{k}$) is then

$$W=Fd=F\biggl [\frac{(F-\mu_{k}mg)}{2m}t^2\biggr ]$$

Hope this helps.